# Laravel 5.5 install

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to install Laravel 5.5 with `laravel new project --dev`

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]           
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL), expecting ']'
```

It is just me or because it is not release yet?

EDIT:
Btw, it is when I try to make `php artisan key:generate`... If I put any key in .env it works...

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide all updated via *EDIT* main question, not by comments. With version of PHP do you have?

Comment: For me composer was the issue, Because i was running Laravel new blog command.

Answer (score 28):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog  "5.5.*" --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 8):

To install Laravel 5.5 you need launch composer create-project as usual and you need to set the “dev-develop” version of the laravel/laravel package:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog dev-develop
```

Where:

- laravel/laravel: is the package for Laravel installation;
- blog: is the new directory for your new project (you can change it);
- dev-develop: is the next version of Laravel.

Yuo can find more information here
https://medium.com/@robertodev/how-to-install-laravel-5-5-dev-d721873a8c89

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
For me even

```
php artisan
```

did not work.

I fixed it with a simple

```
cd /my/project/folder
composer update
php artisan key:generate
```

in the console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: They fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your **Laravel Installer** version. I have faced the same problem.

Run following command:

`composer global update` (it will update your Laravel Installer)

If you don't want to install again, then fix by following command:

`composer update` (from your project directory and it will update your project files)

### Additional:

Sometimes, it may cause of **Composer** version. You can update your composer version by following command:
`composer self-update`

Then you can update your project files.

Hope this answer will help you.